# Como exportar registros no SQL sem duplicados?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou tentando remover alguns registros duplicados de uma tabela e eu procurei na Internet como fazer isso, e encontrei algo sobre `distinct`.

Meu cenário é:

Eu tenho uma tabela que tem um registro com todas as colunas duplicadas.

> ```
> ID | Nome   | Idade
> 1  | Teste  | 20
> 1  | Teste  | 20
> 1  | Teste  | 20
> 2  | Teste2 | 28
> ```

Agora eu estou tentando exportar para uma tabela temporária com `distinct`, mas quando eu exportar apenas com ID na minha consulta a consulta da certo e exporta sem os duplicados:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.ID
INTO Temp
FROM tabela t
```

no entanto se eu fizer :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
INTO Temp
FROM tabela t
```

Ele exporta tudo até os duplicados.

Como posso exportar todos registros com `distinct` ou sem ele?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack overflow. Da maneira que está sua pergunta ela fornece poucos detalhes para te ajudarmos. Procure informar com detalhes o que você já tentou. Comece fazendo um [tour] e leia o guia [ask].

Comment: Ah, favor inserir também via o link [edit] qual o banco de dados que você está utilizando.

Comment: O banco é o sql gmsantos está lá no titulo. Perdão pela minha falta de experiencia aqui no site sou iniciante mesmo.

Comment: Lucas, sem problemas, com o tempo você vai pegando o jeito. Você se refere ao SQL Server da Microsoft?

Comment: Sim. Coloquei até um exemplo lá de como está a tabela.

Comment: tu tentou usar o group by?

Comment: Nunca usei "apelido.*" com DISTINCT. Informe o nome de todos os campos - `SELECT DISTINCT ID, Nome, Idade INTO Temp FROM tabela` que deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Estou a "roubartilhar" [uma resposta que encontrei no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18949/2263584) ;)

Deves agrupar os registos. Creio que podemos ignorar os ID's repetidos (deixe-me saber se isso não vem a calhar). Portanto vamos utilizar todos os campos exceto o campo ID. Algo parecido com:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, Nome, Idade 
FROM Temp
GROUP BY Nome, Idade
```

Note que podes utilizar *MAX* ao invés de *MIN*... O que importa é obter um único ID para cada grupo de registos duplicados.

Na prática acontece que cada informação distinta do sistema será obtida. E para cada grupo de várias informações repetidas, apenas o menor ID (ou maior, se utilizares *MAX* ao invés de *MIN*) será obtido.

Quando tiveres esses resultados, terá duas alternativas para cumprir teu objetivo:

- Podes exportar o resultado desta consulta. Terás somente os dados distintos no resultado da exportação;
- A forma menos recomendada é apagar da tabela todos os registos repetidos. Isso requer coragem, pois qualquer erro pode apagar dados além dos que queres apagar. Recomendo ter um backup se quiseres seguir por este caminho.

O comando é qualquer coisa parecido com o seguinte:

```
DELETE * 
FROM Temp
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, Nome, Idade
    FROM Temp
GROUP BY Nome, Idade
) as RegistosAManter ON
Temp.ID = RegistosAManter.ID
WHERE
   RegistosAManter.ID IS NULL
```

A consulta a partir do FROM recupera todos os registos da tabela. Os ID's de cada registo aparecem duas vezes (porque estamos a usar um JOIN), mas do lado direito do resultado ficarão nulos os ID's dos elementos repetidos. O comando de apagar irá remover da tabela esses registos.

Comment: O campo ID não está variando sempre, segundo a pergunta.

Comment: @Caffé valeu! Vou editar aqui :)

Comment: Se for usar GROUP BY, `SELECT ID, Nome, Idade FROM Temp GROUP BY ID, Nome, Idade` resolve o problema. Não precisa função de agreção.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o comando `INTERSECT` ele remove linhas duplicadas da consulta final.

```
SELECT *
FROM   SuaTabela
WHERE  ColunaDesejada BETWEEN 1 AND 100

INTERSECT

SELECT *
FROM   SuaTabela
WHERE  ColunaDesejada BETWEEN 50 AND 200;
```

Espero que lhe ajude.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente acredito que sua modelagem "mesmo que para testes" deve existir uma chave primária, o qual **não** deveria permitir que a coluna "**ID**" receba duplicidade, mas OK, vamos partir para algo como testes.

nesse caso, acredito que somente resolva utilizando o group by.

```
create table t (ID int, Nome varchar(20), Idade int)
go

insert into t values 
(1, 'Teste', 20),
(1, 'Teste', 20),
(1, 'Teste', 20),
(2, 'Teste', 28)
go

select t.id, t.nome, t.idade , count(1)
from t
group by t.id, t.nome, t.idade
```